# Apply a rolling function with multiple arguments on a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, rolling-computation

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"quantity": [101, 102, 103], "price":[12, 33, 44]})

    price   quantity
0   12      101
1   33      102
2   44      103
```

I have been struggling to find how to apply a rolling complex function on it.

For simplicity, let's assume this function `f` is just the product of `quantity` and `price`. In this case, how do I apply this function on a rolling window of size `1`, with a scaling parameter, say:

```
scaling = 10
```

such that the resulting dataframe would be:

```
    price   quantity    value
0   12      101         NaN
1   33      102         12120.0
2   44      103         33660.0
```

with `value[i] = price[i-1]*quantity[i-1]*scaling`

I have tried:

```
def f(x,scaling):
    return x['quantity']*x['price']*scaling
df.rolling(window=1).apply(lambda x: f(x,scaling))
```

and

```
def f(quantity,price,scaling):
    return quantity*price*scaling
df.rolling(window=1).apply(lambda x: f(x['quantity'],x['price'],scaling))
```

Could you please help me fixing this **without doing** a simple:

```
df['value'] = df['quantity'].shift(1)*df['price'].shift(1)*scaling
```

?

Comment: Is your resulting dataframe correct? if you want the value[i] be on i-1, then surely the value would be NaN, 12120, 33660?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I will update the question. Thanks!

Comment: Is the answer below what you need?

Comment: I think so! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you want is indeed `value[i] = price[i-1] * quantity[i-1] * scaling` , then:

```
scaling = 10
df['value'] = df.shift(1).apply(lambda x: x['quantity'] * x['price'] * scaling, axis=1)
```

df

```
    quantity    price   value
0   101         12      NaN
1   102         33      12120.0
2   103         44      33660.0
```